# Implementing RFC 8693 Token Exchange with Azure AD for a Non-JWT OAuth2 Token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, identity, token-exchange

I manage an Security Token Service (STS) labeled as "A," and it currently issues access tokens in the form of a Standard OAuth2 token (non-JWT). I'm exploring the possibility of implementing the token exchange protocol outlined in RFC 8693 with Azure AD.

Essentially, I want to provide Azure AD with an access token from STS "A" along with the necessary fields specified in the RFC 8693, aiming to receive a valid access_token from Azure in return.

I've looked into the Azure on_behalf_of OAuth2 flow, and it seems close to what I need. However, it requires the input access_token to be in JWT format, which my STS currently does not support. Are there any suggestions or alternative approaches for achieving token exchange between my OAuth2-based STS and Azure AD?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm quite sure the OBO flow requires a token signed by Azure AD, not a token from another authority. Not sure if this is achievable.

Comment: Hey Junnas! I'm not 100% sure. In a related scenario, someone was able to perform a token exchange between Azure and another identity provider (OpenIdDict). However, in that case, the initial token was obtained from Azure AD. I want my initial token to come from the other identity provider. https://damienbod.com/2023/01/09/implement-the-oauth-2-0-token-exchange-delegated-flow-between-an-azure-ad-api-and-an-api-protected-using-openiddict/